# difference between "and" and "such that" in logical statements

Tags: logic

For the contrary statement of the following:
there exists a,r>0 such that f(x) > a, for all x in B(x_0,r)

is the contrary statement:
 1. for all a,r > 0, there exists an x in B(x_0,r) such that f(x) $\leq$ a
 or
 2. for all a,r > 0, there exists an x in B(x_0,r) and f(x) $\leq$ a?

Basically, the two differ by the "such that" and "and" term. I feel like (in common English) they would mean the same, but logically in math would the first one be the correct one (so the second is logically incorrect)?

Comment: The phrase "such that" does not appear in logical statements when they are written in purely symbolic form. The phrase only appears in natural-language in places where a condition has to be specific. It may help if you start by writing the original formula in purely symbolic form, with no natural language.

Comment: Isn't such that usually denoted with a colon ":"?

Answer (score 2):

Let's put it this way: in mathematical logic, "and" conjoins two statements (informally, you can think of them as clauses with verbs);
also, "and" is commutative.

So let's look for the two statements conjoined by "and."
One of them is, "There exists an $x$ in $B(x_0,r).$"
The other is, "$f(x) \leq a.$"

Since "and" is commutative, we can swap the two statements:

> $f(x) \leq a$ and there exists an $x$ in $B(x_0,r).$

Does that make sense? It doesn't make much sense to me.
The problem is, the word "and" promotes the clause $f(x) \leq a$
to something independent of the $x$ that exists in $B(x_0,r).$
That's not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements could be replaced by the following :

$$(\forall a,r>0) \;\; (\exists x\in E) \;\;:\;$$
$(x\in B (x_0,r)\;\;$ and $\;\; f (x)\le a )$

$E $ is the metric space.

Comment: Thank you. So using the two statements that I posted, then they would both be equivalent?

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 The second you posted is not well formulated.